# Trouble Deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to get students from an api and display their information but am having some trouble deserializing some json that I am retrieving. I am using c#

Here is what is being retrieved:

```
    [
       { 
          "firstName": "John", 
          "lastName: "Smith", 
          "id": "122386144", 
          "schoolYear": "Sophmore", 
          "Links": [
              { 
                 "url": "https://github.com/johnsmith", 
                 "comments": "Click to see some of my projects!"
              }
          ],
          "GPA": "3.6"
        },
        { 
          "firstName": "Jane", 
          "lastName: "Doe", 
          "id": "45624523", 
          "schoolYear": "Junior", 
          "Links": [
              { 
                 "url": "https://linkedin.com/janedoe", 
                 "comments": "Follow me on LinkedIn"
              }
          ],
          "GPA": "3.8"
        }
    ]
```

Here is what I have for my class:

```
public class Student
{
   public string firstName { get; set; }
   public string lastName { get; set; }
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string schoolYear { get; set; }
   public string[] Links { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
   public string url { get; set; }
   public string comments { get; set; }
}
```

And Finally my code deserializing the json. I cannot provide the actual url here so the below baseUrl is just a placeholder for this post:

```
string baseUrl = "https://CodeUniversity.com/"
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
   client.DeafultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
      MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/CS/students");
   
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      var studentResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      studentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>(studentResponse);
   }
}
```

When this code runs I receive the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException', but this dictionary requires a
> model item of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[University.Models.Student]'.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `public string[] Links` for `public Link[] Links { get; set; }`

use this site for convert your [json to c# class](https://app.quicktype.io/)

your models class

```
public partial class Student
    {
        [JsonProperty("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("schoolYear")]
        public string SchoolYear { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Links")]
        public Link[] Links { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("GPA")]
        public string Gpa { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Link
    {
        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public Uri Url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("comments")]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

and deserialize

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student[]>(studentResponse);
```

check example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yCtmQs)

Comment: Thanks, this resolved my issue. Needed to set Link to Link[]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `Links` property of class `Student` should be type of `Links` instead of `string[]`.
I would also suggest renaming the `Links` class to `Link`

Comment: Wow, thanks didn't catch that. Sometimes it helps to have another set of eyes. However, I am now receiving this error after changing the type: _The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[University.Models.Student]'._

Answer (score 0):

there is  a bug in json,  add " to lastName before : . Also fix Links property and add GPA property

```
public class Student
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public  int id { get; set; }
    public string schoolYear { get; set; }
    public double GPA { get; set; }
    public List<Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
   public string url { get; set; }
   public string comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!